# Failed audit: first post

Tags: discussion, review-audits, first-post-review

If I understand the original to all the duplicates to that matter correctly I shall post it here (even if it is a duplicate).

I was tasked with this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19189008

I can not tell if this is really fixing the problem, but as it seems to be quite easy to do I would think the poster did it this way before.

The answer was marked as very poor quality (severe problems, unfixable by an editor). But as long as this is a fix for the original problem. I don't see how this is unfixable. A little make up and it would be good.

If I am mistaken and the given fix would not work, I will quietly leave the room and say no more.

Comment: Please don't *leave the room and say no more*.

Comment: @StephenRauch It was meant as a joke and only regarding this specific incident^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree, this seems off.

I don't know if the answer *works*, but it's not implausible.

I've undeleted it; that'll prevent it from being reused as an audit.

Comment: Undeleted AND no meta effect? Outrageous!